# Regex for any value 50% through 150%

Tags: regex

I'm really not sure how to go about this. I have a range of percents, I'd like to return only those 50% through 150%. How would I do this?

Comment: `^(?:[5-9]\d|1[0-4]\d|150)%`?

Comment: genius thank you! I'm not sure how to make this as the answer.. but it worked perfectly.

Comment: A handy tool for experimentation with regex like this is https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/UXyHVZ/1)

```
^(?:[5-9]\d|1[0-4]\d|150)%
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:[5-9]\d|1[0-4]\d|150)` Match any of the following

  - `[5-9]\d` Matches any digit in the range from `5-9` followed by any digit (matches from `50` to `99`)
  - `1[0-4]\d` Matches `1`, followed by a digit in the range from `1-4`, followed by any digit (matches from `100` to `149`)
  - `150` This one's obvious
- `%` Match this literally